# Container Test1 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start Issue -- Azure Linux web service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am using Azure web app service and trying to connect to Azure Postgres database. I am trying to migrate on-premise JAVA application to Azure.

Using -

- Tomcat version - 9
- JAVA version - 8
- OS - Linux
- Code based

The below settings have been given in the configuration:

App Settings:

1. JAVA_OPTS
   -DPOSTGRESDB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://XXXX.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/postgres?user=XXXX&password=XXXX&sslmode=require
2. WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT = 1800
3. WEBSITES_PORT = 80 (also tired 8080,2222,3000)

The following has been given in the context.xml file and the war file is built and deployed in the app service:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/XXXX" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="${POSTGRESDB_URL}" maxTotal="25" 
maxIdle="10" validationQuery="select 1"/>.
```

- While using the URL to connect to the app, it is giving **application error**.
- In the logs,below error is displayed.
  **Container Test1 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start Issue -- Azure Linux web service**.

**NOTE :** When the username and password details of the database are given in the context.xml file directly, the app is working fine. I am facing the issue only when these details are provided in the app service application settings.

I have checked many posts and followed the provided suggestions in those posts, but the issue is still not resolved. Please provide any inputs how to resolve this error.

Comment: Did you follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/connect-java tutorial or a different tutorial? When the container fails to respond to pings, it's normally a sign that an error occurred during app startup. Please share any errors you see on `https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logs/docker`.

Comment: We are not using any IDE, directly deploying the war file with the context.xml file (code mentioned in the description) and then providing username and password for the database in the app settings of the web app service.
In the Docker logs, same error has been mentioned - didnt respond to HTTP pings

Comment: You can try to use [Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66212658/react-app-not-loading-with-docker-compose/66213919#66213919) to deploy your webapp.

Comment: Can you also provide a larger snippet of your container and application logs? A failure to bind to HTTP is an indicator that the application either took too long to start up or encountered an error during startup.